# Add Remote Glassfish server to Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb

I am a .NET Developer trying to learn Java.  I have created a simple CRUD based EJB application and it works in Netbeans.

I am trying to add a remote Glassfish server (installed on another PC) to Netbeans so that I can deploy the application (EJBs) from Netbeans.  Think of the remote server as a live server (though it is not).

Is it possible to add a remote Glassfish server to Netbeans 7.4.  It only seems to allow you to add a local instance.

Comment: I clearly remember an add remote glassfish functionality in Netbeans 8, but I didn't succeed in making it works in any way I tried, so I gave up after lot of frustration. However, I am not a Netbeans expert but I am quite sure you can add a remote server too in 7.x vesion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have done asadmin enable-secure-admin (etc) on your remote server, the only way I have found is to remotely mount the (physical) server and then you can point Netbeans at the glassfish directory on the remotely mounted server.